# adjust the user session after logging in in Liferay 7, how to get the session?

Tags: java, session, liferay, liferay-7

In liferay 7, I am trying to adjust the user session after the login is successful. I used to build a hook for that, and it used to work just fine. But now I am unable to retrieve the session to inspect an attribute.

```
@Component(immediate = true, property = { "key=login.events.post" }, service = LifecycleAction.class)
public class TestSessionAdjustAction implements LifecycleAction {
@Override

public void processLifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent) throws ActionException {
        final HttpSession session = lifecycleEvent.getSession();
        final TestAccessToken token = (TestAccessToken) session.getAttribute(TestWebkeys.TEST_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        if (token != null) {
            TestSessionUtil.put(token.getRefreshToken(), session);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is throwing a null pointer ex at:

```
session.getAttribute(TestWebkeys.TEST_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

Comment: What does TestSessionUtil do? Why session object is final here?

Comment: The final is just cause of the style guidelines. and the util just checks the code to put it in a mapping logic. But the if is basically inactive here, cause there is no way the attribute is there (I disable the module that put it there).

Comment: so, this guy HttpSession session = lifecycleEvent.getSession(); might be doing something I dont expect. it Is my first time with this components in LR 7 to replace a hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poking around I fund that replacing my problematic line with

> final HttpSession session = lifecycleEvent.getRequest().getSession();

solves the problem. (I hope this helps some one..cause, it took me a while)

It seems like the lifecycleEvent has in its class several constructors and the one being used here, before my method, sets the session to null...

```
public class LifecycleEvent {

public LifecycleEvent() {
    this(null, null, null, null);
}

public LifecycleEvent(
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    this(null, request, response, null);
}

public LifecycleEvent(HttpSession session) {
    this(null, null, null, session);
}

public LifecycleEvent(String[] ids) {
    this(ids, null, null, null);
}

public LifecycleEvent(
    String[] ids, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    HttpSession session) {

    _ids = ids;
    _request = request;
    _response = response;
    _session = session;
}

public String[] getIds() {
    return _ids;
}

public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return _request;
}

public HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
    return _response;
}

public HttpSession getSession() {
    return _session;
}

private final String[] _ids;
private final HttpServletRequest _request;
private final HttpServletResponse _response;
private final HttpSession _session;}
```